# postfix misconfigured: “mail for (domain) loops back to myself”

Tags: debian, postfix, smtp

I've just installed postfix on my debian system, so I have a default configuration, apart from the following values in /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = myhostname, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = mydomain.com
relay_domains = mydomain.com
```

Every email I send to anything@mydomain.com bounces back with the mail server telling me:

```
This is the mail system at host mydomain.com.

I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not
be delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.

For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.

If you do so, please include this problem report. You can
delete your own text from the attached returned message.

                  The mail system

<anything@mydomain.com>: mail for mydomain.com loops back to myself
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that's literally what you have in your `main.cf` then the fix is easy.

You need a $.

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
```

If this doesn't fix it then run `postconf -n` and post the output.